# Can we make SSL connection without Digital Certificate?

Tags: ssl

Can we make SSL connection without Digital Certificate?

I have tried SSL communication with Digital Certificate but is it possible without Digital Certificate?

Regards
Abdul

Comment: Yes, TLS can also work without X.509 certificates (either without any authentication whatsoever, or with other kind of certificates, or pre shared keys). But your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. The wikipedia page gives a good introduction to TLS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake. Then if you have more questions you will need to find the appropriate place. Depending on the question, it might be [su], [sf], or even [security.se] but make sure to read their help section to find out what is ontopic.

Comment: It is possible but insecure.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMevzek